# Driconf error starts in expert mode

Tags: release-juno, hardware

Several days ago install driconf or 3d acceleration as they prefer to call it, but when it starts I get an error and it starts in expert mode and I can not do anything, I have already installed all the drivers both private and free and remains the same
I have a compaq cq57[image]